# Animation figure closing when interval is increased (FuncAnimation)/Explainantion of interval in FuncAnimation

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying write a program for 1D FDTD wave propagation, everything is fine except the interval keyword argument of FuncAnimation. Whenever I increase the interval from 10 (19 to be precise), the animation figure closes before running (exits as soon as it pops up). Now i can easily slow down the animation using time.sleep, but it would be great if i could understand this.  Can somebody please explain me how this interval argument works. Is it, in anyway related to the time required by the function that updates frames which is being called by FuncAnimation? Also what is blit for?

```
import numpy as np                      
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def main():

    #defining dimensions
    xdim=720
    time_tot = 500
    xsource = xdim/2

    #stability factor
    S=1

    #Speed of light
    c=1
    epsilon0=1
    mu0=1

    delta =1                                # Space step
    deltat = S*delta/c                      # Time step

    Ez = np.zeros(xdim)                     # Arrays to store Electric field and magnetic field
    Hy = np.zeros(xdim)

    epsilon = epsilon0*np.ones(xdim)        #Permittivity and permeability values.
    mu = mu0*np.ones(xdim)                  

    fig , axis = plt.subplots(1,1)
    axis.set_xlim(len(Ez))
    axis.set_ylim(-3,3)
    axis.set_title("E Field")
    line, = axis.plot([],[])

    def init():
        line.set_data([],[])
        return line,

    def animate(n, *args, **kwargs):
        Hy[0:xdim-1] = Hy[0:xdim-1]+(delta/(delta*mu[0:xdim-1]))*(Ez[1:xdim]-Ez[0:xdim-1])
        Ez[1:xdim]= Ez[1:xdim]+(delta/(delta*epsilon[1:xdim]))*(Hy[1:xdim]-Hy[0:xdim-1])
        #Ez[xsource] = Ez[xsource] + 30.0*(1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(n-80.0)**2/(100))
        Ez[xsource]=np.sin(2*n*np.pi/180)
        ylims = axis.get_ylim()
        if (abs(np.amax(Ez))>ylims[1]):              # Scaling axis
            axis.set_ylim(-(np.amax(Ez)+2),np.amax(Ez)+2)
        line.set_data(np.arange(len(Ez)),Ez)
        return line,

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=(time_tot), interval=10, blit=False, repeat =False)
    fig.show()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```